# scroll table in both direction with the header fixed only using sass

Tags: angular, html-table, sass

I have a table in angular

```
     <table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let header of objectKeys(tableContents[0])">{{header}}</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let content of tableContents">
    <td *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(content)">{{content[key]}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have to make their height adjust according to the screen and then make the scrollable in both direction with the header fixed and the screen size is going to be that of a mobile.
I tried using many resources given but all used javascript for horizontal scrolling which i can't use.
Here is what i tried..This makes header not scrollable and also reduces it's width.

```
 .table{
border-collapse: collapse;

thead{

    td{
        padding: 4px;
        background-color: $filter-background;
        color: $white;
    }
    tr,td{
        border: 2px solid $input-border2; 
        padding: 2px;
    }
}
tbody{
height:100px;
display: block;
overflow-y: scroll;
    tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: $input-background;
    }
    tr,td{
        border: 2px solid $input-border2; 

    }
    width: 400px;
 }
 display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: sticky` might be what you're looking for.

Try this:

```css
thead td {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

And remove the `overflow` and `height` rules.